# Ruby find query returns array. Can it return a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby has a find function to query the database and return the results in an array.

For Eg:

```
@hotels = Hotel.find(:all, :conditions => something)
```

Is there a way I can get the results in a Ruby hash where I specify the key for each row specific to each object returned in the previous array specific to certain conditions.

Comment: That is old, deprecated syntax. You should be using `where`, eg. `Hotel.where(something)`

Answer (score 2):

Not directly in Rails, but you can use `map` on the result

Example:

```
Hotel.find(:all, :conditions => something).map { |h| {h.id => h.attributes} }
```

Will return an array of hashs.

Or:

```
Hash[ Hotel.find(:all, :conditions => something).map { |h| [h.id, h.attributes] } ]
```

Will return a hash indexed by records id

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you want to do with the result. Perhaps `index_by` might be a handy method for you?

```
Hotel.where(...).index_by(&:id)
# => { 1 => [<Hotel#1, Berlin>], 
#      2 => [<Hotel#2, Berlin>], 
#      3 => [<Hotel#3, Melbourne>] }

Hotel.where(...).index_by(&:city)
# => { 'Berlin'    => [<Hotel#1, Berlin>, <Hotel#2, Berlin>],  
#      'Melbourne' => [<Hotel#3, Melbourne>] }
```

Comment: I didn't know about that method, nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get results as an array of hashes by sidestepping rails' objectification of the sql results:

```
hashes = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("select * from hotels where name = \"foo\"")
```

Note that the keys in the resultant hashes are all strings, not symbols.

I'm not sure what you mean by `where I specify the key for each row specific to each object returned in the previous array specific to certain conditions.`